# Nullpointer Exception in FragmentActivity while showing data in Spinner from database

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, spinner, fragment

I am getting a problem in FrameActivity with FragmentPagerAdapter to declare my swipe-able tabs. In one of tabs contain Spinner in which i want to collect data from database. First i am going to post my FrameActivity

```
     public class TranscationMain extends FragmentActivity implements
  ActionBar.TabListener {
Context context;
private ViewPager viewPager;
Spinner spinner_question ;
ContentValues values;                
SQLiteDatabase sql_lite_db_obj; 
private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
private ActionBar actionBar;
Cursor cursor;
int i =0;
// Tab titles
private String[] tabs = { "Shipped In", "shipped Out", "New Entry" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.transcation_main); 

    AndroidContext.setContext(this);        
    sql_lite_db_obj = DatabaseHelper.getInstance().getDb(); 
    values = new ContentValues();

    // Initilization
    context = this;
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());  

    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);      


    spinner_question = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_category);


    // Adding Tabs
    for (String tab_name : tabs) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name).setTabListener(this));
    }
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });


}  

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(arg0.getPosition());

}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
        public void clickHandler(View v)   
{

    if (v.getId() == R.id.btn_new_category_id) {
        // btn click event that define in NewEntry.java calss
                    // click on this button alert dialog will open with editext
                    // from where i insert data in database. which i have to show in 
                     // spinner which define in same activity. Insertion of data is
                   // done successfully. 
    }

}
     private void insertData(String category) {  
    // method to insert data in database
           // working fine
}
```

Now this is exception part of above code

```
   private void loadSpinnerData() {  
    DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());  
    List<String> lables = db.getAllLabels();  
    System.out.println(" data in array : "+lables);

    // Creating adapter for spinner  
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lables);
    System.out.println(" dapater : "+dataAdapter);

    // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button  
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);  

    // attaching data adapter to spinner  
    spinner_question.setAdapter(dataAdapter);  
}
```

I want to call this method in this block

```
       if (v.getId() == R.id.btn_new_category_id) {
             loadSpinnerData()
              }
```

But always i am getting a NullPointer Exception . Only because of initialization of

```
        spinner_question = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_category);
```

Spinner is not define in above TranscationMain's layout, It define in below Fragment

```
        public class NewEntry extends Fragment{
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       spnr = new Spinner(getActivity());
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_entry, container, false);

    return rootView;
}
```

}

That why i am getting exception in below line.

```
   spinner_question.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Now i didn't understand how can i solve this problem. How can i bind data in spinner in Fragment. I am new fro fragment activity. Thanks in advance to all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Spinner is not define in above TranscationMain's layout, It define in below Fragment
```

This is the reason for the crash.

`findViewById` looks for a view in the current inflated layout.

If the spinner is in fragment you need to initialize the same in fragment and then load the items from database to spinner in fragment.

In fragment

```
Spinner spinner_question;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {

View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_entry, container, false);
spinner_question = (Spinner)rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinner_category);
return rootView;
}
```

Comment: @Raghunandan.. When i am trying to define spinner in Fragment findViewById is not working. Then how i will bind spinner in xml with java file.?

Comment: @Raghunandan...Spinner spnr;     spnr = new Spinner(getActivity());
        loadSpinnerData(); private void loadSpinnerData() {  
        DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());  
        List<String> lables = db.getAllLabels();  
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lables);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);   
        spnr.setAdapter(dataAdapter);  
    }

Comment: @Raghunanadan.. But i am getting error in ArrayAdapetr "The constructor ArrayAdapter<String>(NewEntry, int, List<String>) is undefined"

Comment: @BlueGreen you need to read the docs. `ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lables);`. `this` refers to fragment not activity context

Comment: @BlueGreen what happens now??

Comment: @Raghunandan.. I will follow your suggestion.. Sure.. Thanks again